# Java EE 6.0 and .NET 4.0 comparison

Tags: .net, jakarta-ee

We are running our applications on .NET 3.5 and are planning on either updating to .NET 4.0 or switching entirely to the Java platform, Java EE 6.0, as we've heard from some clients that "it's better."

Can anyone either explain some of the large differences between the two platforms and maybe what kind of costs would be associated with switching to Java rather than just updating, or point me to some articles or papers that make such comparisons?

Thanks!

Comment: While C# and Java have a similar language syntax, that's mostly where the similarities end... the frameworks that come with them are considerably different, a few things (like Collections) being the exception.

Comment: It's a topic that's way to broad to cover in a single article or paper. More specific comparison criteria are needed for anything meaningful to come out of this.

Answer (score 2):

(half smart-alecky, half serious).

Would you prefer these from a pro-.NET bias, or a pro-Java bias? You can find articles with both spins. Your clients are simply biased.

If you've already got trained .NET developers, and a large codebase in .NET, then switching does not make sense, especially if it's that some uninformed customers claim the religious view that Java is "better". 
That said, here's one article.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_vs_.NET

And just to avoid mis-interperetations, I am NOT saying Java is bad.  I think both are good platforms.  The absurdity is in spending time and money in switching, retraining, etc, when .NET is a perfectly good platform.

Comment: +1: No sense is spending time and money to change something that doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: Now if only the project I'm currently on could have been done in .NET in the first place... stupid client insisting that it be in Java for no good reason...